# Case Statement in t-sql view returns wrong number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a view that returns the wrong number of records when I use a case statement to create the data in a field.

```
SELECT a.[Line Id]
```

returns the correct number of records.

I would like to be able to use the following case statement, but it returns the wrong number of records

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN a.[Line Id] LIKE '%FIX%' 
         THEN 'Fixed'
         ELSE 'Variable'  
    END AS 'Fixed/Variable'
```

I have methodically eliminated other parts of the view and determined this is where the confusion is. Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vNew File]
AS
   SELECT distinct 
      [Year]
      ,a.[Co #] + '-LO' + a.[Organization] as 'Receiver'
      ,CASE 
          WHEN a.[Line Id] LIKE '%FIX%' 
            THEN 'Fixed'
            ELSE 'Variable'  
       END AS 'Fixed/Variable'
      ,CASE 
          WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM([Line ID])) = 'SYSXXXXVVSCHG' 
            THEN 'IA-100000'
          WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM([Line ID])) = 'SYSXXXXFIXCHG' 
            THEN 'IA-100040'
          WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM([Line ID])) = 'SYSXXXRFIXCHG' 
            THEN 'IA-031061'
          WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM([Line ID])) = 'SYSXXXUFIXCHG' 
            THEN 'IA-100020'
          WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM([Line ID])) = 'SYSXXXUVVSCHG' 
            THEN 'IA-100010'
          WHEN LEN(a.Activity) > 1 
            THEN 'IA-' + LTRIM(RTRIM(a.Activity))
          ELSE
            'IA-' + LTRIM(RTRIM(b.ActivityNumber))
       end AS 'Activity'
      , CASE 
                WHEN a.[A] = 'A' THEN 'Actual' 
            ELSE 
                'Budget' 
            END 
            AS 'Dataset'
            ,'Dollar' as Value
            , convert(float,a.Jan) as 'Jan'
            , convert(float,a.Feb) as 'Feb'
            , convert(float,a.Mar) as 'Mar'
            , convert(float,a.Apr) as 'Apr'
            , convert(float,a.May) as 'May'
            , convert(float,a.Jun) as 'Jun'
            , convert(float,a.Jul) as 'Jul'
            , convert(float,a.Aug) as 'Aug'
            , convert(float,a.Sep) as 'Sep'
            , convert(float,a.Oct) as 'Oct'
            , convert(float,a.Nov) as 'Nov'
            , convert(float,a.Dec) as 'Dec'
            ,case
                When len(a.[Activity]) < 1 then a.Company + '-LP' + a.[Cost Center]
                when a.[Activity] = '700148' then '00001-LPXXXXCH.9999' --+ b.[OrgUnit]
            ELSE
                 '00001-LPXXXXNFT.9999'
            END 
            as  'Provider'
   FROM 
       [DPEs].[dbo].[April YTD New DPE File Actuals] a 
   JOIN 
       DPEs.dbo.SBUToActivity b ON LTRIM(RTRIM(a.[Cost Center])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(b.[OrgUnit]))
   WHERE  
       [YEAR] = 2014
    GO
```

Comment: An expression in the `select` does not change the number of rows being output.  Hence, there is something else wrong with your query.

Comment: show us you `WHERE` clause

Comment: Here is the whole view

Comment: The issue is the `distinct`.  You should edit your question with sample data and desired results as well.

Comment: Distinct is indeed the issue. Thank you for your assistance.